# Pagination meta tag rel next, vs link attribute?

Tags: pagination

I am implementing a product listing. Google recommends having rel next and prev meta tags.

Would rel next and prev attributes on appropriate anchor tags, achieve the same result? Or is that completely different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rel` attribute [is valid](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a.attrs.rel) on `a` elements. However, Google's best practices state that it expects a [prev/next/canonical `link`](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html) to be in the `<header>`.